# time conversion to float

Tags: php

I wrote code to convert the float value of time and convert it into hours and minutes. If input 2.5 it will return 2:30 (2 hours and 30 minutes).

```
$input = '2:5'; 
$num_hours=str_replace(":",".",$input,$num_hours) ;
$hours = floor($num_hours);
$mins = round(($num_hours - $hours) * 60);
echo  $hour_one = $hours.'.'.$mins;
```

but now I want to reverse it:  if input `2:30` it should return `2.5`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the modulo `%` operator for the first operation:

```
$value = 2.5;
echo floor($value) . ':' . (($value * 60) % 60);
```

Output:

```
2:30
```

---

To convert them back you can use:

```
$value = "2:30";

$parts = explode(':', $value);
echo $parts[0] + floor(($parts[1]/60)*100) / 100 . PHP_EOL;
```

```
2.5
```

AS a function we can use :

```
function hours_tofloat($val){
    if (empty($val)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $parts = explode(':', $val);
    return $parts[0] + floor(($parts[1]/60)*100) / 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $input);

echo $hours . '.' . $minutes / 60 * 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

**i think this is your answer try this**

```
<?php
$str = str_replace(":", ".", "2:5");
$float_value = floatval($str);  // this Line Convertit une chaîne en nombre à virgule flottante

echo $float_value;  

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getPartialTime($sTime)
{
    $aTime = explode(':', $sTime); 
    if (isset($aTime[1]) {
        $iPart = round($aTime[1]*100/60);
    } else {
        $iPart = 0;
    }

    return $aTime[0].'.'.$iPart;
}
```

This will return on getPartialTime('2:30') => 2.5