# How to convert h:m:s to float and float to h:m:s php

Tags: php, time

I want to convert time value with second to float and than do some calculation on it and convert it again to time value using php

I have used the function describe below but it has only hour and minute calculation it display wrong amount if second value is there.

i found this function from [time conversion to float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24390749/time-conversion-to-float)

I have used function for convert time to float is

```
function hours_tofloat($val){
    if (empty($val)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $parts = explode(':', $val);
    return $parts[0] + floor(($parts[1]/60)*100) / 100;
}
```

`hours_tofloat("00:02:37");`
if i use above function for `00:02:37` time value it gives me wrong float no `0.03` because above function dose not have option for second. so help me and guide how to calculate it

Comment: Why do you want to convert to float? Floating points won't be accurate(but approximate) anyway.

Comment: I have to do calculation on time value. and addition and subtraction in time value not working well

Comment: Converting them to an integer timestamp should work well. In other words, convert the whole thing into seconds and then do the math.

Comment: it create problem in negative time value  like minus 04:30:00 hour

Comment: So you would have time as `-04:30:00` ? Just multiply that final seconds by `-1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use EPOCH time routines? Epoch time is an integer representing seconds based on 1 Jan 1970. You don't need the date part so you can have the following approach:

```
<?php
  $time = '00:02:37';
  $date = new DateTime("1970-01-01T$time+00:00");
  echo 'Seconds = '.$date->format('U');
?>
```

Output

```
Seconds = 157
```

Answer (score 3):

Modify your code as follows. It will return the time in `seconds`.

```
$val = '00:02:37';
function hours_tofloat($val){
    if (empty($val)) {
        return 0;
    }
    $parts = explode(':', $val);
    return (int) (($parts[0] * 60 *60) + $parts[1]*60 + $parts[2]);
}

echo hours_tofloat($val);
```

Output: `00:02:37 = 157`

It returns

`157`

Comment: Integer would be better - see the first comment above

Comment: Yes, the help seeker prefers to convert it into float. That's why converting it to float instead of an integer.

Comment: Just because they say they prefer it doesn't make it a good idea. More likely they just didn't realise it could cause inaccuracies. Our job is also to provide the best solution, not just to blindly follow all requests exactly, no matter what

Comment: @ADyson Thank you for your excellent suggestion. Ok, I've updated the code and will keep it in my mind in my following answer.

Comment: No problem. Have an upvote.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237982/discussion-between-mainul-hasan-and-adyson).

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = "00:02:37";
/* function converts time value to float */
function time_to_float($val){
 $parts = explode(':', $val);
 $hour_val = 0;
 $hour_val = $parts[0];
 $min_val    = $parts[1]; 
 $second_val = $parts[2]; 
 return ($hour_val +(($min_val* 1/60))+($second_val * 1/3600));
}
$value = time_to_float($val);// 0.043611111111111

/* function to convert float to time */
$res = float_to_time($value);//00:02:37

 function float_to_time($value){
    $value1 = explode('.',$value);
    $hours = $value1[0];
    $min_in_float = ($value - $hours) * 60/1;
    $min_val = explode('.',$min_in_float);
    $min_val = $min_val[0];
    $min_in_float = $min_in_float - $min_val;
    $second_val = $min_in_float * 60/1;
    $second_val = round($second_val);
    if($hours < 10){
        $hours = "0".$hours;
    }
    if($min_val < 10){
        $min_val = "0".$min_val;
    }
    if($second_val < 10){
        $second_val = "0".$second_val;
    }
    
    return $hours.":".$min_val.":".$second_val;
 }
```

I got reference about the calculation from

https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/time-to-decimal-calculator.php
https://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/time/decimal-to-time-calculator.php

Answer (score 0):

With [strtotime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) I get the seconds immediately. UTC must be used as the time zone.

```
$time = '00:02:37';
$seconds = strtotime('1970-01-01 '.$time.' UTC'); //157
```

[gmdate](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php) can be used to convert an integer into a time H:i:s.

```
$seconds = 157;
$timeHis = gmdate('H:i:s',strtotime('1970-01-01 UTC +'.$seconds.' Seconds'));
//'00:02:37'
```

The number of hours must not exceed 23 and the number of seconds $seconds must be less than 86400 (= 1 Day). Negative times are also not supported.